# Sql conditional Join on different tables

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

I've to add a notification module on an existing project. 
My table structure is like on the pic.

Picture :[image: conditionalJoin]

as you see on the picture every notification has  a type and a releatedID.

Type 1 = reservation is cancelled, releated ID is the id on "reservations" table

Type 3 = account balance is under the given min. limit  so releatedID is the id on "account_movements" 
table

what I'm trying to do is a conditional join to avoid 2 different sql queries;

1. Get all notifications which are belong to the person
2. Get notification details from different tables based on "notification.Type"

So the question is can I do it in one query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work. Basically you specify which records in your `notifications` table join with records in your `reservations` table or your `account_movements` table when you join those in. Use a LEFT JOIN so that ALL of your `notification` records make it through, and only those records in the `reservations` table OR the `account_movements` that have a match make it through.

```
SELECT 
  n.id,
  n.type,
  n.companyid,
  n.personid,
  n.relatedid,
  n.description,
  r.details as reservation_details,
  am.details as account_movement_details,
  COALESCE(r.details, am.details) AS combined_detail
FROM
  notifications n
  LEFT OUTER JOIN reservations r ON
    n.relatedid = r.id AND
    n.type = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN account_movements am ON
    n.relatedid = am.id AND
    n.type = 3
```

Here is a [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31e87/3) with the solution as well.

I added in the `COALESCE()` just to show that since the JOINS are mutually exclusive, you can safely combine columns from your `reservations` table and your `account_movements` table into a single column without fear of missing or duplicating any data.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a left join, you won't have to have any condition :

```
SELECT * FROM notifications n
LEFT JOIN reservations r ON n.releatedID = r.id
LEFT JOIN account_movements m ON m.releatedID = m.id
```

Comment: What happens if both reservation and account_movements tables have an entry which has the ID that is equal to the releatedID? Wouldn't I become than the entries from both tables?

Comment: If there are a records in reservation and account_movements, you'll get a row with all the notifications datas, all the reservation datas and all the account_movements data, each of them prefixed with their table name. It's in the code you'll do after your query that you'll take the notification type in account and keep reservation or account_movement datas accordingly.

Comment: @JNevill answer is more complete and allow to retrieve only the needed datas.

Comment: This is a worthy solution, but you would probably need to do some extensive `CASE`, `IF`, or `COALESCE` on each `reservation` and/or `account_movement` record in the `SELECT` clause AND a `GROUP BY` overall to keep `notifications` records from duplicating. It could get a little hairy if you throw an asterisk into the `SELECT` clause though.