# Conditional join on tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, conditional-statements

I want to create a conditional join on tables.

I already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715656/sql-conditional-join-on-different-tables). But I also read that an `OUTER JOIN` might not be the best way (performance wise) since a full table scan still takes place? And there also seems to be difference in opinion on the performance of using `UNION`.

What is the way I can conditionally join tables based on my requirements below?
ps. If your solution requires it, I can implement this as a stored procedure too to create some more dynamic SQL.

For all rows where userfavorites.objecttype=100, based on the value of `photos.objecttype` I want to join another table.
If the `objecttype` value is 1 I want to join `[locations]`, if the value is 2 I want to join `[persons]`.

As output I want the following columns:
photos.title,photos.locpath, (persons.title or locations.title), (persons.friendlyurl or locations.friendlyurl),userfavorites.objectid,userfavorites.objecttype

I now have this to get the rows for a single user:

```
SELECT * FROM userfavorites uf
INNER JOIN photos vp ON uf.objectid=vp.id
WHERE uf.objecttype=100 AND uf.userid='32DD30EB-1691-457B-9FF5-FC41D687E579'
```

DDL and insert statements:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[photos](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [objectid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [locpath] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [objecttype] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](50) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[userfavorites](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [userid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [objectid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [objecttype] [tinyint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_userfavorites_objecttype]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_userfavorites] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[persons](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [friendlyurl] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_persons_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[locations](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [friendlyurl] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_locations_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]




USE [tt]
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[userfavorites] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[userfavorites] ([userid], [objectid], [objecttype]) VALUES (N'32dd30eb-1691-457b-9ff5-fc41d687e579', 41029, 100)
INSERT [dbo].[userfavorites] ([userid], [objectid], [objecttype]) VALUES (N'32dd30eb-1691-457b-9ff5-fc41d687e579', 41030, 100)
INSERT [dbo].[userfavorites] ([userid], [objectid], [objecttype]) VALUES (N'32dd30eb-1691-457b-9ff5-fc41d687e579', 40880, 100)
INSERT [dbo].[userfavorites] ([userid], [objectid], [objecttype]) VALUES (N'32dd30eb-1691-457b-9ff5-fc41d687e579', 40885, 100)
INSERT [dbo].[userfavorites] ([userid], [objectid], [objecttype]) VALUES (N'32dd30eb-1691-457b-9ff5-fc41d687e579', 40882, 100)
INSERT [dbo].[userfavorites] ([userid], [objectid], [objecttype]) VALUES (N'32dd30eb-1691-457b-9ff5-fc41d687e579', 4067, 100)
INSERT [dbo].[userfavorites] ([userid], [objectid], [objecttype]) VALUES (N'BC5EB8A7-FEC2-4932-9C67-AE5A35C4012B', 4067, 100)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[userfavorites] OFF

INSERT [dbo].[photos] ([id], [objectid], [objecttype], [locpath], [title]) VALUES (41029, 1, 1, N'hiltonsky.jpg', N'Overview')
INSERT [dbo].[photos] ([id], [objectid], [objecttype], [locpath], [title]) VALUES (41030, 1, 1, N'pool.jpg', N'Swimming')
INSERT [dbo].[photos] ([id], [objectid], [objecttype], [locpath], [title]) VALUES (40880, 2, 1, N'entrance.jpg', N'Lobby Entrance')
INSERT [dbo].[photos] ([id], [objectid], [objecttype], [locpath], [title]) VALUES (40885, 2, 1, N'room.jpg', N'Room view')
INSERT [dbo].[photos] ([id], [objectid], [objecttype], [locpath], [title]) VALUES (40882, 1, 2, N'zuck.jpg', N'Mark')
INSERT [dbo].[photos] ([id], [objectid], [objecttype], [locpath], [title]) VALUES (4067, 2, 2, N'gates.jpg', N'Bill')
INSERT [dbo].[photos] ([id], [objectid], [objecttype], [locpath], [title]) VALUES (50673, 3, 2, N'musk.jpg', N'Elon')

INSERT [dbo].[locations] ([id], [title], [friendlyurl]) VALUES (1, N'Hilton Hotel', 'hilton-hotel')
INSERT [dbo].[locations] ([id], [title], [friendlyurl]) VALUES (2, N'Marriot Hotel', 'marriot-hotel')


INSERT [dbo].[persons] ([id], [title], [friendlyurl]) VALUES (1, N'Mark Zuckerberg', 'mark-zuckerberg')
INSERT [dbo].[persons] ([id], [title], [friendlyurl]) VALUES (2, N'Bill Gates', 'bill-gates')
INSERT [dbo].[persons] ([id], [title], [friendlyurl]) VALUES (3, N'Elon Musk', 'elon-musk')
```

So for userid `32dd30eb-1691-457b-9ff5-fc41d687e579`, the outcome would be:

```
+----------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+------------+
|   phototitle   |    locpath    |      title      |   friendlyurl   | objectid | objecttype |
+----------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| Overview       | hiltonsky.jpg | Hilton Hotel    | hilton-hotel    |        1 |          1 |
| Swimming       | pool.jpg      | Hilton Hotel    | hilton-hotel    |        1 |          1 |
| Lobby Entrance | entrance.jpg  | Marriot Hotel   | marriot-hotel   |        2 |          1 |
| Room view      | room.jpg      | Marriot Hotel   | marriot-hotel   |        2 |          1 |
| Mark           | zuck.jpg      | Mark Zuckerberg | mark-zuckerberg |        1 |          2 |
| Bill           | gates.jpg     | Bill Gates      | bill-gates      |        2 |          2 |
+----------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: You should fix the formatting of your query, especially at your rep level.  Your query looks fine to me, without further information.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: thank you for the feedback! What exactly was wrong with my query formatting? I thought I marked it as a code block already. And how were you able to so quickly format my desired query results? Thank you (even at my rep level...still learning :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with outer joins and it seems to be the straight forward approach to the problem. Whether or not a full table scan will be used is up to the DBMS; it will decide for the fastest data access whichever that may be.

```
SELECT 
  vp.phototitle, 
  vp.locpath, 
  coalesce(l.title, p.title) as title, 
  coalesce(l.friendlyurl, p.friendlyurl) as friendlyurl, 
  uf.objectid, 
  uf.objecttype
FROM userfavorites uf
INNER JOIN photos vp ON uf.objectid = vp.id
LEFT JOIN locations l on vp.objecttype= 1 and vp.objectid = l.id
LEFT JOIN persons p on vp.objecttype= 2 and vp.objectid = p.id
WHERE uf.objecttype = 100 AND uf.userid = '32DD30EB-1691-457B-9FF5-FC41D687E579';
```

However, if the table persons and locations are really very similar you might want to consider making them a single table with a flag saying whether a record is a person or a location. That would make things easier and speed up access.

Comment: Do not join distinct entities in the same table, ever. If there is no difference between tracking the people in a photo and tracking the location in a photo, then they are the *same entity* and no flag should be used to distinguish them.  Otherwise there must be some attribute that distinguishes them. For example, people can be male or female (or other genders, perhaps); while locations can be indoor or outdoor, foreign or domestic, hot or rainy ...

Comment: @Ross Presser: The flag *is* the attribut that distinguishes them. How else would you select all photos of persons, when persons and locations are in the same table? But yes, there can be more attributes and then it is to decide whether to have one table with the one or the other set of attributes filled or two tables each with its own attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as 
( SELECT * FROM userfavorites uf
  INNER JOIN photos vp ON uf.objectid=vp.id
  WHERE uf.objecttype=100 AND uf.userid='32DD30EB-1691-457B-9FF5-FC41D687E579' )
SELECT * 
from cte 
JOIN locations on cte.objecttype = 1 and cte.objectid = locations.id
union all
SELECT * 
from cte 
JOIN persons   on cte.objecttype = 2 and cte.objectid = persons.id
```